# ¡Primer Concurso del 2016!

Tags: discusión

Este nuevo año me ha motivado para traerles unos concursos.  Este sera el primero de varios este año así que pónganse las pilas que vamos a comenzar.

### Concurso #1 - La medalla de “Anunciante”

Durante las fechas del **18 de enero** hasta el **15 de febrero** entregaremos una camiseta oficial de Stack Overflow a todos los que cumplan lo siguiente:

- ganar la medalla de “[**Anunciante**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/59/announcer)”

Para poder permitir que el sistema les acredite los enlaces, deberán usar el enlace oficial encontrado al final de las preguntas al pinchar el botón de *compartir*

[image: Compartir]

Solo así podremos verificar quien merezca la medalla y quien se gane la camiseta. No valdrán los enlaces compartidos antes del lunes, 18 de enero así que no les conviene empezar antes de tiempo.

### Pero eso no es todo…

[image: Hay Mas]

Para poder hacer este concurso un poco mas interesante, también les dare oportunidad de completar lo siguiente:

- ganar la medalla de “[**Altruista**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/48/altruist)”
- ganar la medalla de “[**Curioso**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/87/curious)”

Noten que una pregunta que sea bien recibida quiere decir: [**una pregunta que este abierta, no eliminada, y que tenga una puntuación de >0**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges)

Termina estos dos pasos adicionales y entraras al concurso para ganar (1) cuaderno con el logotipo de Stack Overflow impreso en la portada y (2) una colección de calcomanías.

Tienen aproximadamente un poco mas de 4 semanas para este concurso.  Pienso que es tiempo suficiente para completar los requisitos.  Se deberá ganar la medalla de "**Anunciante**" antes de poder pedir los premios de las otras dos medallas.  Sin la medalla de "**Anunciante**" no se gana nada.

¡Buena suerte a todos!

---

Algunos de ustedes ya tienen las 3 medallas mencionadas, y eso no es problema siempre y cuando vuelvan a ganar la medalla de "**Anunciante**." Esa es la única que voy a requerir que se gane de nuevo para poder pedir cualquiera de los premios.

Comment: Juan, y si ya tenemos una de las medallas???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????? :D :D :D :D

Comment: @CésarBustíos creo que deberias tener dobles puntos o algo asi ;)

Comment: el unico que tiene una de las medallas es @rnrneverdies - solamente el necesita ganerse las que le faltan

Comment: gracias! a los ganadores, les darán un tracking number para saber como va llegando el premio?

Comment: @JuanM estamos hablando de medallas Meta?

Comment: @JuanM Nopes, yo también tengo la medalla "Curioso". Aunque de todas formas supongo que no sería muy legal si yo participara. :-)

Comment: @Konamiman no entendí muy bien, en SOes si tengo curioso, aca en Meta no tengo ninguna pero supongo que se refiere a medallas en SOes.

Comment: Si, discupa, me equivoque. Esto es para el sitio normal, no para Meta.  Si alguien ya gano las medallas entonces puede pedir su premio!  La única medalla que se debe volver a ganar es la de Anunciante.

Comment: @JuanM perfecto!

Comment: Se vale compartir las respuestas o solo las preguntas?

Comment: @JuanK cualquiera de las dos :)

Comment: Para lo de las medallas "Altruista" y "Curioso" cuenta desde ya? porque ya ofrecí mi primer bounty.

Comment: @JuanK ya somos dos! :-)

Comment: Habría que mandar también un enlace al perfil de SOes, ¿no? si no, ¿cómo sabrías que la persona que envía el email de verdad ha conseguido las medallas?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro voy a comparar los email de los perfiles con los que reciba - deben ser los mismos.

Comment: Yo lo acabo de ver :(

Comment: @JuanM ¿el enlace se debe compartir en la plataforma de StackEchange? O si, por ejemplo, comparto una pregunta en twitter o facebook para encontrar respuesta también es valido?

Comment: @JuanM ¿Cuántos van reclamando el premio? :)

Comment: @JordiCastilla El enlace se comparte por las redes sociales usando el enlace que el sistema genera.  No lo compartas en la plataforma de StackExchange.

Comment: @Gepser Vi tu email - voy a crear un Google Form para poder acumular los datos de los ganadores en manera más eficiente. Anunciare el final del concurso y el enlace en cuanto el concurso termine.

Comment: Me interesa tener estas medallas, espero poder obtenerlas para una camiseta!

Comment: Hola, una consulta, ¿es válido compartir una respuesta en vez de una pregunta para tratar de ganar el tag de "anunciante"?

Comment: @manix Si, es valido compartir una respuesta. :)

Comment: @JuanM Una pregunta Juan, con respecto a la medalla "Anunciante", al compartir la respuesta por twitter genera este link :  http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/972/95?stw=2 , ese link es suficiente para que ustedes registren el acceso por diferentes IP?

Comment: me rebota el correo que envio  a  garza@stackoverflow.com, esta bien escrito?

Comment: @DanielHernández es `jgarza`

Comment: Se puede hacer seguimiento de la medalla "Anunciante" ?

Comment: @Alan No hay forma de realizar el seguimiento, tal vez para los administradores como Juan, en mi caso después de compartir el link y asegurarme se abra por más de 25 ocasiones en ips distintas no obtengo la medalla... :(, me resulta un poco raro ya que veo algunos si la obtuvieron.

Comment: Claro tenía esa duda, si se podía ver de alguna forma ya que seguramente publicamos varios links y no hay forma de corroborarlo.  Gracias @Elenasys

Comment: Creo que tienen que ser 25 ocasiones distintas y que vengan de fuera de StackOverflow (si alguien está navegando SOes y pulsa en el título de la pregunta, el contador de visitas sube pero no cuenta para la medalla Anunciante)

Comment: Gracias por la información @AlvaroMontoro , sin embargo esto seguro que las personas que han abierto mi enlace, no están autenticados en stackoverflow. =(, saludos!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

¡Se termino el concurso!

Felicidades a todos y gracias por participar en un este gran evento.

Los ganadores de la medalla de "Anunciante" (y su camiseta oficial de SO) son:

- [brasofilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/238/brasofilo)
- [JuanK](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/398/juank)
- [Shaz](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/73/shaz)

Los ganadores de las medallas de "Anunciante, Altruista, y Curioso" (y su camiseta oficial de SO, cuaderno con emblema de SO, y una colección de calcomanías) son:

- [Gepser](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/399/gepser)
- [Daniel Hernández](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2509/daniel-hern%C3%A1ndez)
- [rnrneverdies](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/25/rnrneverdies)
- [Goerman](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/1184/goerman)

**¡Felicidades a los ganadores!**

Comment: Esperamos los resultados con ansias.

Comment: @rnrneverdies muy cierto....mis disculpas.

Comment: Yo gané varias medallas anunciante, hay un premio por ello? ;) http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/59/announcer?userid=398

Comment: @JuanK lamentablemente no - ¡pero sí, me di cuenta!

Comment: Seguiré intentando =), me gustaría tener un t-shirt!

Comment: Alguien recibió su premio ya? :p

Comment: @rnd a mi no me ha llegado ...

Comment: @Goerman fijate en el chat, JuanM ha comentado que hubo un problema en la aduana y tienen que reenviar los paquetes. Tiene una estrella y fue ayer el comentario asi que sera facil de encontar.

Comment: @Goerman http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28316898#28316898

Comment: Ya llegó mi premio XD, que felicidad tan amarilla.https://goo.gl/htPgbs