# ¿Seria bueno implementar un sistema de referencias para invitar a nuevos usuarios a SO-es?

Tags: característica-nueva

Recientemente he estado invitando a varias personas a unirse, colaborar y hacerse de un nombre en la comunidad y se me ocurrió que tal vez seria bueno tener alguna forma de dar seguimiento a las personas que invitas y tener alguna bonificación de reputación.

**¿Que piensan al respecto?**

Comment: Si es de reputación, puedes decirle a tus amigos que voten tus respuestas. Fuera de esa broma, no sé si una bonificación de reputación sería lo más adecuado, pero sí me parece interesante la idea. Yo creo que un poco de swag sería mejor. Swag = camiseta + stickers. Pero claro, no depende de mí, ese tipo de cosas se le podrían consultar a @JuanM.

Comment: Si la verdad no suena tan mal y te motivaría un poco mas a participar en la comunidad.

Comment: Genial tu actitud. Y me sumo a la propuesta para traer más usuarios... En cuanto a una bonificación es difícil medirlo sin desarrollar una método para generar invitaciones, pero quizás se puede pensar en premios para quienes tengan la medalla de [Anunciante](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/59/announcer).

Comment: @mariano eso ya se hizo http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/381/primer-concurso-del-2016 "*Para poder permitir que el sistema les acredite los enlaces, deberán usar el enlace oficial encontrado al final de las preguntas al pinchar el botón de compartir*"

Comment: @JordiCastilla Gracias. No sabía. No lo había leído.

Comment: Aaaah yo tampoco sabia!

Answer (score 1):

De los comentarios a la pregunta

[Mariano](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/127/mariano) :

Genial tu actitud. Y me sumo a la propuesta para traer más usuarios... En cuanto a una bonificación es difícil medirlo sin desarrollar una método para generar invitaciones, pero quizás se puede pensar en premios para quienes tengan la medalla de [Anunciante](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/59/announcer).

[Jordi Castilla](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/517/jordi-castilla) :

@mariano eso ya se hizo [¡Primer Concurso del 2016!](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381/primer-concurso-del-2016) *"Para poder permitir que el sistema les acredite los enlaces, deberán usar el enlace oficial encontrado al final de las preguntas al pinchar el botón de compartir"*

> NOTA: La transcripción se debe a que los comentarios tiene la finalidad de ser temporales, principalmente para para criticar constructivamente las publicaciones, ya sean pregunta o respuestas. Las repuestas deberían publicarse como respuestas, en lugar de hacerlo como comentarios.