# ¿Existirán Concursos este año?

Tags: discusión

El año anterior se realizaron dos concursos interesantes

1. [Primer concurso del 2016](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381/primer-concurso-del-2016?rq=1)
2. [Segundo concurso del 2016](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/685/segundo-concurso-del-2016-fechas-editadas?rq=1)

**¿Se hará algo parecido este año?**

Es algo positivo para el sitio ya que se fomenta la participación de la comunidad.

Comment: El segundo concurso fue realmente un fiasco (en mi opinión), tanto así que uno de los ganadores era un usuario inactivo.

Answer (score 2):

¡Si! Tendremos otros concursos este año. Muy pronto empezaremos. ;)